# Unloading swf from parent swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfloader

So I loaded a swf into another swf like so

*correctURL being my external swf variable*

function startLoad(){

```
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(correctURL.toString());
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
mLoader.load(mRequest);
```

}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event) 
{

```
    var gmc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    gmc.x = 266;
    gmc.y = 67;
    addChild(gmc);
    gmc.addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.loader);
```

}

But i'm struggling to unload the damn thing when I want to replace it with another swf.

The code i'm trying is this

function closeAllStreams(e:Event) {

```
    e.currentTarget.loader.unloadAndStop();
    gmc = null;
    gmc.removeChild(e.currentTarget.loader);
    trace("unloaded");
```

}

mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, closeAllStreams);

I'm just not having any luck as I can still hear the old sound over the top.

I don't want to access the loaded swf's variables either or i'd just cheat haha.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unloadAndStop() will work with only Flash-Player 10 and then you dont need to assign null to loader reference, this method does itself. Your closeAllStreams method will be called after this statement

e.currentTarget.loader.unloadAndStop();
OR
e.currentTarget.loader.unload();

so its better not to call it inside the unload Event dispatcher i.e closeAllStreams  in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a problem anyway:

```
gmc = null; 
gmc.removeChild(e.currentTarget.loader);
```

Do I need to explain why

Comment: That's usually the idea with stackoverfow yeah ;), unless it's become pointoutheissueanddontsolveit.com?? :)